Is Swirling a noun?
I have got a title composition from AI "Swirlings of simple Things".
Also in the Leo online dictionary is Swirling listed as a noun (https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/swirling).
But I wanted be sure, can swirling be used as a noun?
Many thanks for your help in advance!

Grammatically, you can use any present participle as a noun. But "Swirlings of Simple Things" is a very strange phrase; I have no idea what it means.

swirlings (with an s) is particularly odd.

I am in search for the title of an art-work. What about "Circling", can circling be used with plural "s"? I.e. Circlings

You might get suggestions from stackexchange literature, but I think this an Off Topic "matter of opinion" for ELU.

Wiktionary gives this as a noun, with the plural form swirlings. But it's unusual in the plural.

[I am in search of a title for a work of art] Is it art like painting and sculpture? Like a mobile?

Sounds like a gerund, a verb used as a noun.

Your research shows it's a noun, but it wouldn't matter for titles. Consider Dali's bizarre melting clock in "The Persistence of Memory." The art and title are both strange, but there it is. Swirling Swimmingly and Circlitudeness.

What do you mean by "in search of"? There's an artwork with this title and you're trying to find it? Or you've created an artwork, and you're trying to find a good title for it?

If you're creating a title, you can do whatever you want. Titles don't have to be grammatical.

@FumbleFingers It would be off-topic over at Literature.SE, too.

@Barmar It's my own work, I am choosing a title for it.

Leo marks it as technical and relating to automobiles. So is that relevant?

Almost certainly a duplicate. Gerund ending in 'ings'? was closed as a duplicate of How can I prove a word is a noun?

If you can use the definite or indefinite articles with it, it's a noun.

It refers to the flattening of all pretty people features into a
single, cyborgian look -- a swirling of Hollywood archetypes,
social media beauty ideals, and facial filters. (Business
Insider)
The word " whirl " is often associated with rapid, spinning movements,
as in the motion of a spinning top or the swirling of water.
(Forbes)

Nouns also inflect for number, which swirling does.

At times she paints a little like Van Gogh -- great swirlings of
cloud, as in one of the Dutchman's late, mystical visions of the night
sky (Independent)
Here a whirlpool boils with mud and immense
swirlings of water,
spouting up the slimy sand of Cocytos. (Theoi)

Nouns also have genitive forms, which, though rare, swirling does indeed have.

Intermittently step back and evaluate the vortex effect’s progress.
Make adjustments as required to refine the swirling’s shape,
intensity, and heading. (ITS)

According to these common tests for nouns, there is in fact a noun in use with the spelling swirling.

Quite a nice comprehensive answer with great usage examples for an unusual word!
